# 3-Dimensional Representation of SU(2)

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Just to level set everyone here, I am not a mathematician, so I will likely need this answer to be in a bit more plain english than the standard fare. I've been reading an intro to elementary particles textbook, which is essentially and intro to Quantum Field Theory. And in the book the author, Griffiths, gives a very, very short explanation about symmetry and symmetry groups. And he makes the following statement at one point,

"Similarly, particles of spin 1, described by vectors, belong to the three-dimensional representation of SU(2);"

I searched around and found this previous question on this site.

[How can SU(2) group has 3 dimensional representation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192159/how-can-su2-group-has-3-dimensional-representation/2192198#2192198?newreg=a05784f4b83c4fb58462ad86e79eafa7)

Which was helpful in describing how to construct higher dimensional representations of SU(2) like Griffiths is referring to. But I still have one question I haven't been able to find an answer to.

If I were to give you a 3 dimensional matrix such as the U matrix constructed in the answer given to the question above, how would you be able to categorize it as a 3-dimensional representation of SU(2) as opposed to simply being the fundamental representation of SU(3)?

Comment: I think you mean $SO(3)$ not $SU(3)$ ?

Comment: If I use MATLAB to build a test matrix using random numbers for my angles, I get a matrix that is both unitary and orthogonal. I'm guessing orthogonal trumps unitary and thus we would define it as belonging to SO(3)? But what about higher dimensions? You can have a 4D representation of SU(2) as well. I guess I'm just trying to figure out why you say something is a higher dimensional representation of SU(2) vs being in SU(n) or SO(n).

Comment: Is it just a matter of the basis in which you're operating? So I've seen some info that talks about how in the SU(2) mapping of SO(3) a 360 degree rotation returns a -1 and you need a 720 degree rotation to get back to 1, versus a a 360 degree rotation in SO(3). So the J matrices are the same for a 3D representation of SU(2) as those of SO(3) but if the action of U where $\Theta$ is $2\pi$ returns a -1 then it is in SU(2) vs SO(3)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "give you a $3$-dimensional matrix." A representation is not a matrix; it is a function from $SU(2)$ (or whatever group) to matrices (which is a homomorphism etc.). The codomain of the function being $SU(2)$ is what makes it a representation of $SU(2)$, by definition.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan So in the context of the question I referenced, the function $U = exp(i\theta_x J_x + i\theta_y J_y + i\theta_z J_z)$ is what belongs to SU(2) and thus by plugging in the correct nxn J matrices, you get the n dimensional representation of SU(2)? So SO(3) has some other function for U which can be used to construct SO(3) matrices?

Comment: @SCossano: if I understand your question correctly, basically yes. It sounds like you are trying to write down a representation of $SU(2)$ by exponentiating a representation of its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, and yes, that works. If you want to write down a representation of $SU(3)$ (I assume you meant this and not $SO(3)$) you'd use a different Lie algebra, which among other things is $8$-dimensional and not $3$-dimensional.